# Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following error occurred on my web application while postback,

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I figured out the solution adding following code to web.config file:

```
<pages
    buffer="true"
    masterPageFile="~/masterpages/Main.Master"
    enableEventValidation="false">
</pages>
```

However adding the secondary code, will there be a security concern? Are there alternatives to achieve the same with better security control?

Comment: You haven' shown anything of your page, so how could be help to fix the issue? What is causing the error? Where do you modify controls at clientside?

Comment: i have completed localization in my project and when i add  enableEventValidation="false" in web.config it works perfectly but when we use this code there will be problem in security purpose so i was asking if there is any alternative for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do like this in your Page_Load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{ 
//do something 
}
```

may this will help you.

Comment: Has the solution for this changed or did MS break something here recently as of 4/24/23? I have a that had been working fine for years but is now throwing this error out of nowhere but using `EnableEventValidation="false"` in the related <@Page> or `enableEventValidation="false"` in the app's web.config doesn't seem to be fixing it.

Full error: https://gist.github.com/cemerson/12b4b44acd5f58fc6574a4efaf9c46ba